# How to handle n-ary tree with this structure

Tags: c, list, struct, tree

I want to implement and handle a n-ary tree as a struct with a key and a pointed list of childs. I have came up with this structure:

```
struct ntree {
     int key;
     list *childs;
}
typedef struct ntree ntree;

struct list {
    struct list *next;
    struct ntree *child;
}
typedef struct list list;
```

I wonder whether this is the correct way to do it. I also need a function to insert a node, delete a node and print the tree.

Comment: Yes, you need a function to insert a node,delete a node and print the tree. Better though is to have one function per functionality.

Comment: The struct definitions seem to be fine. Have you alread tried to implement the functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Except that you forgot ';' after '}', and you use the type list before you define it, it is okay, but I would not make `child` in `struct list` a pointer:

```
struct ntree child;
```

Numquam ponenda est pointers sine necessitate.

Maybe you may want to store also pointer to the parent in the structure ntree. It might make your life easier.

The name `child` is misleading.